# Cargar vista parcial editar en modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero cargar la vista parcial editar dentro de un modal y me sale este error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Sí me pueden ayudar estaría bastante agradecido.

He intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero no lo he conseguido no sé porque me da error al parecer pensé que estaba todo bien

```
    <td class="wrap-td">
  <a href="#ModalEditar" class="btnEdit btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-id=" @position.PositionID"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o u-mr-xsmall"></i></a>
  </td>

<div class="modal" id="ModalEditar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="color:black"><i class="mdi mdi-book-open"></i> EDITAR TIPO DE DOCUMENTO</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form class="c-card__body formAjaxAdd" method="post" action="~/Positions/Edit">
                    <div id="modal-content">

                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(".btnEdit").click(function (eve) {
        debugger;
        $("#modal-content").load("/Positions/Edit/" + $(this).data("id"));
    })
</script>
```

Controlador

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
    {
        EditPositionsViewModels model = new EditPositionsViewModels();

        var position = PositionsService.Instance.GetPositions(ID);
        model.PotionID = position.PositionID;
        model.Name = position.Name;
        model.Description = position.Description;
        model.Salary = position.Salary;
        return PartialView("_EditPosition", model);
    }
```

Comment: 2 cosas: 1.- Por vista parcial te refieres a la mitad de un modal? o te refieres a la mitad de información de un formulario? y 2.- El error 500 se debe a un error de conexión con el servidor, dice que no encuentra la información. Tal vez el problema en si es otro.

Comment: Tengo una vista parcial llamada _EditPosition es donde se encuentran el contenido del modal editar, nose porque sale el error